# Automating AB Tests in Journey Builder for SMS & Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush, sms, ab-testing

I am trying to figure out a way to automate AB tests for Push and SMS in Journey Builder. As it stands now, the only option for path optimizer for SMS and Push is to manually select and send to the winner of the AB test. Not ideal if there are a lot of SMS/Push campaigns.

My initial thought was to create a new data field in any DEs being evaluated that populates via link tracking. From there the Journey evaluation criteria would pick the winner using decision splits and a conversion event?

Can someone help me think this thru a few more steps and potentially share a map of how you could achieve this without having to manually send to winner in JB, or is this not achievable whatsoever thru JB. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.